# Change order in y-direction of stacked bar chart in ggplot2 as indicated by sequence

Tags: r, ggplot2, colorbar, geom-bar, geom-col

using this reproducible example `tibble`

```
 # install and attach packages
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, dplyr, ggplot2)  

# Create example dataset (tib1)
tib1 = tibble(location = c("loc1", rep(c("loc1", "loc2"), 8), rep("loc2",2)),
              drill = sort(c(1, rep(1:4, 4),4, 4)),
              thickness = c(20, 34, 99, 67, 29, 22, 53, 93, 64, 98, 76, 42, 49, 23, 11, 74, 
                            19, 50, 40),
              soiltype = c("gravel", rep( c("sand", "loam", "clay"),5 ), "sand", "gravel", "clay")) %>% 
  arrange(location, drill)

tib1 <- tib1 %>% group_by(location, drill) %>% 
  mutate(order = row_number(),
         bottom_of_layer = cumsum(thickness),
         top_of_layer = bottom_of_layer-thickness) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(location, drill, bottom_of_layer, top_of_layer, thickness, soiltype, order)

tib1
```

I would like to plot a cross section of a soil. I attempt to do this with `geom_bar` or `geom_col` from `ggplot2`. In the example data there is an order given (1:3). I would like the bars to be stacked in the order as specified in the "order column".
So this would implicate that the bar where:

- *location == "loc2"* and *drill == 4* should be colored in the order (from top to bottom):

*orange (loam) - yellow (sand) - grey(gravel) - seagreen (clay)*

AND

- *location == "loc1"* and *drill == 1* should be colored in the order (from top to bottom):

*grey(gravel) - yellow (sand) -  seagreen (clay)*

**While the other stacked bars remain in the same order & color**.

In other words: I need the colors in the stacked bar to vary along with the sequence as indicated in the column "order".

```
colpalette = c("darkseagreen3", "darkgrey", "#FF9966", "palegoldenrod")

ggplot(tib1,
       aes(x = drill))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill = soiltype, y = -thickness),
           stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = colpalette)+
  facet_wrap(vars(location), scale = "free_x")+
  xlab("drill")+
  ylab("depth (cm)")+
  ggtitle("how to plot the bars in the 'preferred order'? ",
          subtitle = "the order of loc2 and drill == 4 should be: loam-sand-gravel-clay")+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: cross section of soil profile with geom_bar]

Comparable, but slightly different issues are:

> [Order of stacked bars ggplot2 - Soil profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46858014/order-of-stacked-bars-ggplot2-soil-profile)
> and
> [Change the order of Stacked Bar Chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090363/change-the-order-of-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)

I wonder whether the thing I am asking for is possible at all in ggplot as:

> Bar charts are automatically stacked when multiple bars are placed at
> the same location. The order of the fill is designed to match the
> legend.

So I might have to search for an alternative option... unless anyone has a hack?
Any help, answers, alternative plotting options, links are appreciated :)
I prefer ggplot2 if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`geom_col` and `geom_bar` are not the appropriate `ggplot2` functions when you want the fill or color to vary along with the sequence as the *fill* and or *color* are grouped in one bar. `geom_rect` is able to seperate two layer of *fill* or *color* within a bar/rectangle.

```
p1 <- ggplot(tib1)+
  geom_rect(data = tib1,
            aes(x = NULL, NULL, 
                xmin = drill-0.45, xmax = drill+0.45,
                fill = soiltype,
                ymin = -bottom_of_layer, ymax = -top_of_layer))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = colpalette)+
  facet_wrap(vars(location))+
  xlab("drill")+
  ylab("depth (cm)")+
  ggtitle("how to plot the bars in the 'preferred order'? ",
          subtitle = "the order of loc2 and drill == 4 should be: loam-sand-gravel-clay")+
  theme_minimal()

  # Optional:
  # Adding in text the column called "order"
p1 + geom_text(aes(x = drill,
                y = (bottom_of_layer + top_of_layer)/-2,
                label = order))
```

This is also possible with discrete x-axis values:
[how do I use geom_rect with discrete axis values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32642856/how-do-i-use-geom-rect-with-discrete-axis-values)

[image: Soil profile plot with geom_rect]

Answer (score 1):

You should order the levels:

ie:

```
tib1 <- tib1 %>% 
    mutate(soiltype = ordered(soiltype, c("clay", "gravel", "sand", "loam")))

colpalette = c("darkseagreen3", "darkgrey","palegoldenrod","#FF9966")

ggplot(tib1,
       aes(x = drill))+
    geom_bar(aes(fill = soiltype, y = -thickness),
             stat = "identity")+
    scale_fill_manual(values = colpalette)+
    facet_wrap(vars(location), scale = "free_x")+
    xlab("drill")+
    ylab("depth (cm)")+
    ggtitle("how to plot the bars in the 'preferred order'? ",
            subtitle = "the order of loc2 and drill == 4 should be: loam-sand-gravel-clay")+
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Onyambu, but I need the colors to be ordered by the order specified in the column. This means that for some soil profiles the sequence of colors is different than for others:

So soil profile A might be from top to bottom: "yellow - green - yellow - orange"

While soil profile B might have totally different order, lets say: "green - orange - yellow"
being in the same plot.

Is this possible in ggplot? if not so, is there another package that could provide a solution?

Comment: @T.BruceLee different ordering in the same plot? That is quite a task. Never seen that before. But probably you could consider ordering the ordering the levels differently within each subgroup(Dont really know whether this could work-Probably not).

Comment: Yes, its an odd question. As ggplot2 is not designed to visualize in that way. But worth a try nonetheless.